# Applying a fill(color) to an SVG image

Tags: css, svg

I've been trying to apply a different color using `fill` to a svg with no success. No idea what I am doing wrong! This is my **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/labanino/hhoa8v9e/)**. Thanks.

Comment: You'd need to put the fill in the image file. Images are not externally modifiable (consider them as having the capability of raster images and you won't go far wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change an SVG image in an `img` tag. You should inline the SVG image in your HTML like so:

```
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
     <path d="M0 0h24v24h-24z" fill="none"/>
     <path class="check" d="M12 1l-9 4v6c0 5.55 3.84 10.74 9 12 5.16-1.26 9-6.45 9-12v-6l-9-4zm-2 16l-4-4 1.41-1.41 2.59 2.58 6.59-6.59 1.41 1.42-8 8z"/>
 </svg>
```

Comment: So, I get the `<svg><path/></svg>` in Illustrator with `SVG code` then? or there is other way?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. You can use Illustrator, Inkscape, or just about any text editor to open an SVG image to view the markup.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the color of an svg file. You need to have the actual svg tag with paths and not an img tag.

http://jsfiddle.net/hhoa8v9e/1/

```
<svg width="4cm" height="4cm" viewBox="0 0 400 400"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" id="triangle">
  <path d="M 100 100 L 300 100 L 200 300 z"
         stroke="blue" stroke-width="3" />
</svg>


#triangle {
    fill:blue;
}
```